# Facebox 1.2 Hide event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, facebox

I am using [facebox](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/) in one of my projects. Is there a event to get the close/hide event of the box?
onHide is not available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the doc's for it: http://github.com/defunkt/facebox/blob/master/facebox.js#L52

```
$(document).bind('close.facebox', function () {
    // Facebox is closing :O
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the quick response. Small question, I have a web page, inside that  I have a iframe, Inside the iframe I am using the facebox. so when facebox comes up i want it to show in the full page, not inside the iframe. is it possible to show it like this ?

Comment: @kakopappa: Is the iframe on the same domain as your page?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the parent window of the iframe with `window.parent` so here is what you should have.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("a[rel*=facebox]").click(function () { 
    window.parent.$.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' });
  });
});
```

that is assuming you use the 'rel' attribute to load facebox modals!